# D flip-flop using basic gates + Clear

Tags: reset

I'm using Logisim to make basic circuits and they have in-built things such as Counter and D Flip-Flop. The D Flip-Flop looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Lh4DQxt.png]

It however doesn't show how it's made up of the basic gates (NAND, NOT, etc). I'm wanting to know how to create a D Flip-flop that can clear if Clear is equal to 1. I've tried searching it up but only get more complicated approaches to what I'm after.

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good section on [gated D latches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Gated_D_latch) and [D flipflops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#D_flip-flop).  (For the difference, read the article.) It should be trivial to add a clear input to either of these.

Answer (score 1):

￼￼￼Although there exists such device (CMOS 4013), you could look up into the [4013 datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/CD/CD4013BC.pdf) on page 2 and see how they did it.
Also that weird TG block if you don't know what that is, it is a Transmission Gate.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate